# What is the aqueous solution for DNA immobilization?

Tags: dna, microarray

This paper
[Electric-field assisted immobilization and hybridization of DNA oligomers on thin-film microchips](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0957-4484/16/10/014/pdf)

Which is talking about how the electric field improve the DNA immobilization process.

Unfortunately, I have no biology background, I could only understand about 50%  contents.

In the section 2.3.1, its says "the chip was exposed to a aqueous solution of the DNA probe".

What is the aqueous solution of the DNA probe?
Is it DD water (DI water) + DNA? or it is some kind of buffer solution + DNA?

Comment: The methods mention a BSA buffer with reference 14 and a borate buffer with reference 30 for immobilizing on their 2 different types of chip. They also mention an SSC buffer, which is a saline sodium citrate buffer commonly used in DNA or RNA hybridization experiments.

Comment: But where they mention about BSA buffer if at DNA hybridization step. The solution is the same with DNA immobilization?

Comment: And in the 2nd type chip with E-assist experiment (section 2.4), They said "a solution of FITC-labelled ssDNA probes with a volume of 2 cm3 is added" which is different from "a 0.5 µM ssDNA probe solution in borate buffer" (section 2.3.2). The previous one did mention about in borate buffer but later one no. Should they be the same?

Comment: You're right to point out the BSA, the SiO2 crosslinking relies on either a thiol or amine reaction, and BSA could interfere with those reactions. They may have used the borate buffer for immobilization on both chips, or they may have just added water to their oligos directly from the manufacturer, in which case the buffer would be whatever salt the manufacturer provided. This seems unlikely, as most DNA storage solutions are typically a Tris buffered EDTA. I have only looked at the methods section, I don't have time to read the whole thing. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail explanation, it is very helpful.  :)